# Create custom site template with JSOM?

Tags: site-template, sharepoint-hosted-app, jsom

I understand that I can create subsites on the hostweb of O365 using JSOM and use custom site templates for that. One (out of many) examples for that can be found at [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/987306/Create-Subsite-with-Custom-Web-Template-Using-Java)

Now my question is: How do I get those template into the host- or appweb in the first place? Can I install my own template using JSOM or does this have to be done manually by the admin?